# Need advice on workflow of MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I am new to programming and working in C# and learning MVC.  I have finally undertaken my first personal project to put to practice what I have been learning from the books/tutorials I have been following.  My project is your typical store that list products, has a shopping cart, user account, admin site...etc.

I have managed to wire up NHibernate to my MySQL DB, and posting records to a view.

My question is "where should I start?".  It seems I could go a lot of different directions, Admin site to manage the site and products, getting the products showing on the site as I would like, User accounts.  What is some advice of how I "should" tackle each component?

I leaning towards the admin site since logically putting products in the store comes before showing the products on your store.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are also going to want to build your application in Web Forms at the same time. You are going to see how Web Forms is much better for well designed applications than MVC, which is for building small sites and not enterprise applications.

Comment: @Mitch... see my comment on @gerry's answer. I'm sorry but you are SOOO mistaken.

Comment: I live in Alberta Canada, where OIL is KING. Many major oil companies are moving their hosted "systems" (not just sites) to ASP.NET MVC.  This is a multi-billion dollar industry relying on MVC for the majority of their hosted systems... including payroll, reporting, etc.

Comment: Oh, and look at StackOverflow.  With how many thousands of page views a day, generating how much revenue, and helping developers how many times... yup that's right ... ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: and lastly... -1 for not answering the question.

Comment: I don't really like to flame but this kind of comment really shows that you either have never used MVC or didn't understand it when you did. ASP.NET MVC needs to replace webforms as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with @Tod

Pick a portion of the website that is needed and build it.  Build up your model (include a viewmodel), then your controller, and finally your view.

In my case, I chose to start with Users.

1. I created my Database and Users Table (no I didn't use code first or EF)
2. Then I created the LINQ DBML file
3. Then I created as super simple repository that talks to the LINQ classes
4. Next I created a service layer that does a little more heavy lifting before communicating with the repository layer
5. Following that, I build a ViewModel that would "transform" data that was to be used in the view. This also included building some HtmlHelpers and Extension Methods.
6. Now to my controller. I build new ViewModel object, pass an object to the ViewModel, and then `return` the viewmodel to the view.
7. Lastly I implemented the View, did my CSS and Markup.

So when I visit the site, I don't see a whole lot except for a nice finished Users section.  This also includes a sign-up area, login area, etc.

Now that the Users section is finished, my next big section is "Events" whereby I will start the process all over again.

Comment: Except the most valuable part of the product from the customer's perspective was done last, and the database model might be incorrect based upon what you end up needing to display (you might be missing a field).

Comment: Well I suppose that the FIRST step is to know what the hell you need to build.

Comment: I disagree.  The first step is to have a fairly good idea what you will build.  Inevitably this will evolve and change dramatically from what you originally envisaged, especially with customer feedback.

Comment: whether your start with your domain first or your view first... your inevitable changes will need to be made on one end or the other, so the point is moot.

Answer (score 1):

Start with what you can use first. If you can't put products in the system, what good is "getting the products showing on the site as I would like". On the other hand, having a site where you can enter products may be (somewhat) useful on it's own.

Even though you are the client, ask yourself: what is the smallest piece of functionality you could build that would be useful for your client? Build that first!

Good luck! Enjoy programming!

Answer (score 1):

I guess its a bit of a personal preference.  For me, I'd rather work on the front end customer facing stuff first, ie: rending products, shopping cart, purchasing and checkout.

The admin side of things doesn't really add value to the product from a customer perspective.  In a less than ideal situation you could release your store without an admin interface, and manage products directly in the database (not ideal), but you could still release it and sell products to the public.

The admin side doesn't add that kind of value, and even if you can add and remove products from the system, you still can't release the product as customers can't see or buy them.

I like to focus on what adds the most value first and build from there - in practice however this isn't always possible.

Either way though, I think taking it from which ever direction you're more comfortable with is the best approach.  If logically you find it easier to conceptualize the process of ordering products when they've already been added to the system from an Admin panel, start at the admin panel.

If you find it easier to build an edit product page based on what you've determined you need to render on the public facing page, then start with product listing and build management around it.

Answer (score 0):

The user account stuff is used throughout your site so you should create that first. The shopping cart is going to be associated with the user account.

Answer (score -1):

Ok going by your question, in my opinion, you might want to find yourself a specific goal, like doing a website for someone that owns a business that you know (this is what I've done, and so have a couple friends of mine).

I've found that the more specific the aim, the better the coding experience. So if you're motivated to a particular project then you'll know what's necessary to do. Give yourself a project to do like a music library utility for example, and see where it takes you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice  However, I think you missed the question.  I have already started a project.  And I listed what the project is about and what I have done so far, but was looking for specific direction in the MVC site I am working on.